# How to catch an exception when any Thread/Runnable/Callable in an ExecutorService fails while awaiting termination

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, future, executorservice

I currently have code that looks something like this:

```
public void doThings() {
    int numThreads = 4;
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {

        final int index = i;
        Runnable runnable = () -> {

            // do things based on index
        };

        threadPool.execute(runnable);

    }

    threadPool.shutdown();

    try {
        // I'd like to catch exceptions here from any of the runnables
        threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Utils.throwRuntimeInterruptedException(e);
    }
}
```

Basically I create a lot of work to do in parallel and wait for it all to be done. If any of that processing fails I need to know quickly and abort it all. `threadPool.awaitTermination` doesn't seem to notice if an exception was thrown inside one of the threads. I just see a stacktrace in the console.

I don't know a lot about concurrency so I'm a bit lost in all the available interfaces/objects such as `Callable`, `Future`, `Task`, etc.

I see that `threadPool.invokeAll(callables)` will give me a `List<Future>` and `Future.get()` can throw exceptions from within the thread, but if I call this on (if the callable throws an exception in its own thread). But if I `.get` each callable I have in a sequential collection then I won't know about the last one failing until all the others have finished.

My best guess is to have a queue on which the runnables put a `Boolean` for success or failure and then `take()` from the queue as many times as there are threads.

I feel like this is an inordinate amount of complexity (even just the code I've pasted is somewhat surprisingly long) for what seems like a very common, simple use case. And this doesn't even include aborting the runnables when one fails. There has to be a better way, and as a beginner I don't know it.

Comment: You can use the `shutdownNow()` method to stop all the threads. Call this method when one of the operations fail.

Comment: Thanks, that'll help. I guess I should ensure that each runnable is regularly running something like `if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) throw new RuntimeException();`?

Comment: An exception would probably only be appropriate when using a Callable. With a Runnable a return statement should suffice no ?

Comment: @Johannes no because the place where I would check for interruption is deep down, not directly in the `run` method.

Comment: You could use a shared "errorFlag" and abort operation if set. That's the part about signaling the other threads. You must check it regularly, of course, but interruption must be supported similarly anyway. To set it you could surround all of your code in `run` with one big try/catch that in the catch sets the errorFlag. That's what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found that `ExecutorCompletionService` is designed for this. I then wrote the following class to abstract the process and simplify usage a bit:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * Wrapper around an ExecutorService that allows you to easily submit Callables, get results via iteration,
 * and handle failure quickly. When a submitted callable throws an exception in its thread this
 * will result in a RuntimeException when iterating over results. Typical usage is as follows:
 *
 * <ol>
 *     <li>Create an ExecutorService and pass it to the constructor.</li>
 *     <li>Create Callables and ensure that they respond to interruption, e.g. regularly call: <pre>{@code
 *     if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
           throw new RuntimeException("The thread was interrupted, likely indicating failure in a sibling thread.");
 *     }}</pre></li>
 *     <li>Pass the callables to the submit() method.</li>
 *     <li>Call finishedSubmitting().</li>
 *     <li>Iterate over this object (e.g. with a foreach loop) to get results from the callables.
 *     Each iteration will block waiting for the next result.
 *     If one of the callables throws an unhandled exception or the thread is interrupted during iteration
 *     then ExecutorService.shutdownNow() will be called resulting in all still running callables being interrupted,
 *     and a RuntimeException will be thrown </li>
 * </ol>
 */
public class ExecutorServiceResultsHandler<V> implements Iterable<V> {

    private ExecutorCompletionService<V> completionService;
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    AtomicInteger taskCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public ExecutorServiceResultsHandler(ExecutorService executorService) {
        this.executorService = executorService;
        completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<V>(executorService);
    }

    public void submit(Callable<V> task) {
        completionService.submit(task);
        taskCount.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public void finishedSubmitting() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<V> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<V>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return taskCount.getAndDecrement() > 0;
            }

            @Override
            public V next() {
                Exception exception;
                try {
                    return completionService.take().get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    exception = e;
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    exception = e;
                }
                executorService.shutdownNow();
                executorService = null;
                completionService = null;
                throw new RuntimeException(exception);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method to wait for the callables to finish for when you don't care about the results.
     */
    public void awaitCompletion() {
        for (V ignored : this) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

}
```